How to Remove/Delete Material Output node from all Materials on a specific object?
I'm on Blender 4.0
I've been trying to make a script to disable all materials in the .blend file.
In my approach here I've tried to delete all material output nodes.
My initial intent was to make it work for the selected objects, But I think it needs to wait.
This was my attempt at it but, I can't make it work.
import bpy
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if mat.node_tree:
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type == 'ShaderNodeOutputMaterial':
                node.remove()

In case Deleting a Material Output node is not possible through Python, I'd like to know if there's any way to disconnect it for all materials.

node.mute = True or mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(node) are work.

How do I get the reference to the Output Node?

Do you mean the node group users or the items that connected to the Output Node socket? These two answers can be obtained by searching old posts.
